# display japanese utf-8 on tera term (or suggest a terminal program for windows that does)

Tags: utf-8, terminal, character-encoding, non-ascii-characters, teraterm

first time posting, so if this is in the wrong place, just let loose and tear into me I don't care. anyway...

straight to the point: I want to display utf-8 encoded japanese characters on tera term, and following instructions I found here (https://ttssh2.osdn.jp/manual/en/usage/unicode.html) is not working. I have looked in other places too and didn't see any different answers that solved my core problem, how to display utf-8 japanese characters in my terminal software whatever that terminal software may be.

Backstory: I'm english speaking by default, but I have this software I'd like to test that spits out utf-8 japanese characters. It does so correctly as far as I know because if I output to a utf-8 text file the characters show up correctly in notepad++. to rule out the software as the issue, if I display the characters from the utf-8 text file on the terminal this also shows wrong. to rule out any terminal server issues, if I set up two terminals to talk to each other directly through virtual com ports, the characters also show up wrong (just ??? or ‹ãB depending on font settings)

If notepad++ can display utf-8 japanese characters correctly, why can't my terminal software? and what do I do?

I'm on windows 7

Answer (score -1):

I recommend you try detecting file encoding using terminal, then open file with that guessed encoding using Notepad++ or any text editors that allow to change encoding (most of them do, most users don't know how to do so though).

```
nkf --guess file.txt
#or aka
nkf -g file.txt
```

alternatively, try using other terminal software like Poderosa or RLogin if on Windows, iTerm/2 if on Mac.